# detect scroll up and down using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollFunc(e) {
userScroll=true;
    if ( typeof scrollFunc.x == 'undefined' ) {
        scrollFunc.x=window.pageXOffset;
        scrollFunc.y=window.pageYOffset;
    }
    var diffX=scrollFunc.x-window.pageXOffset;
    var diffY=scrollFunc.y-window.pageYOffset;
if(userScroll)
{
if( diffY<0 ) {
         $(".myCar").animate({"top": "+=50px"},1000);// Scroll down
        alert('down');
        //$(".myCar").stop();
    } else if( diffY>0 ) {
        $(".myCar").animate({"top": "-=50px"},1000);

        alert('Up');// Scroll up
    } else {
        // First scroll event
    }
    userScroll=false;
}
else
{

}
    scrollFunc.x=window.pageXOffset;
    scrollFunc.y=window.pageYOffset;
}
window.onscroll=scrollFunc
</script>
```

I'm trying to detect, scrolling up and down, but, it showing alert msg for both, i mean, if i'm scrolling down or up, it is showing both alert msg. Need Help.!!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/aricaj/2/edit This script seems not the effect anyone would like to see/use... Btw... where is the error?

Comment: @Roko are you asking to me....??? this is what, i asked in my question..

Comment: @coders... Mozilla latest = works 'fine'

Comment: What are you tracing? i mean scroll up/down or scroll left/right?

Comment: @Roko agree...!! but what about other browser... so you have any solution..??

Comment: @RakeshHolkar right now, i'm just trying to trace up/down. can you help me..??

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me (tested in Opera and Firefox). However, looking at your code, I guess you want the `onscroll` event only fired once per scroll "action" instead of multiple times.

If this is your intention, you could use the custom `scrollstart` and `scrollstop` events described/implemented in [this article](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/)...

```
function animateCar(upDown) {
    $(".myCar").animate({"top": (upDown == 1) ? "+=50px" : "-=50px"}, 1000);
}

(function(){
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(window).on("scrollstart", function(){
        lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    });
    $(window).on("scrollstop", function(){
        animateCar(lastScrollTop - $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ? -1 : 1);
    });
})();
```

[**DEMO** (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Aletheios/hWmNj/)

If you want to keep the original behavior of your code, you could rewrite it using jQuery - perhaps it solves the errors that you're experiencing:

```
$(window).scroll((function(){
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    return function(){
        $(".myCar").animate({"top": (lastScrollTop - $(this).scrollTop() < 0) ? "+=50px" : "-=50px"}, 1000);
        lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    };
})());
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but make it simpler than you. anyway thanks for the your help !! :-)